# 3 Masks in The Man in the Iron Mask

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-iron-mask

In the movie [The Man in the Iron Mask (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120744/) in the scene where the three musketeers want to free [Philippe](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0091414/) (Leonorado De Caprio), Philippe has one iron mask on (mask 1). They then make another mask (mask 2) and they put it on some corpse which they use in the escape. This body is then quickly burned. After they leave, they send that same mask (mask 1) to [Louis](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0006258/) (also played by De Caprio). In a **subsequent** scene, you see Philippe looking at his mask (mask 3? mask 1?)

I realize they could have made 100 masks and sent them to all corners of Paris, but was this intentional or is it a plot hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't have backing-up evidence on my answer. Its according to my viewpoint.

As for the first and second masks (the one Philippe was wearing originally and the mask put on the corpse) are intentionally created. So as to give more of a sense of the deception (the escape) to the viewer. The viewer senses that they kept the original mask (to be sent to Louis) and put-on a second, fake mask on the corpse to help them escape.

As for the third mask, I think its a plot-hole (he couldn't have got the mask that was sent to Louis earlier and they wouldn't have created another similar mask just to keep looking at it).

This is my personal viewpoint and may not be accurate. So please don't vote me down if this answer proves to be wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible the that the mask Louis received was from the prison -- they sent it to him so he would know his brother is dead. This is why there is ash (or something like it) on the mask when Louis picks it up, it was from when the corpse was burned. Anne is crying afterwards because she thinks her son is dead.

Still though, there was no charring on the mask and it all seems a bit out of place... that's why I'm here I suppose.

Comment: Exactly, this is the correct answer. The prison staff simply sent the mask from the fake corpse to *Louis* to show him that the prisoner he once let incarcerate was finally dead (and has been cremated).